# Are there list view url parameters to export to Excel?

Tags: list, excel, export

I would like to automatically export a list view to Excel as a single click process. Are there parameters I can add to the list view url that will accomplish this? The list view is currently provided as a page link that the user then needs to export to Excel.

Comment: Welcome to [SharePoint Stack Exchange](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/tour). Please include what you have tried so far. Also, which SharePoint version/edition you're using? Check [this](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/101701/35471) [answers](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/15546/export-custom-list-to-excel?rq=1) or look for related questions _those questions are available at the right side of the screen_.

Answer (score 2):

List views can be export to excel by passing List GUID & List View GUID with the URL as mentioned below : 
`https://<siteurl>/_vti_bin/owssvr.dll?CS=109&Using=_layouts/query.iqy&List={<List GUID>}&View={<List View GUID>}&CacheControl=1`

You can easily give this url in a button click in your page. Make sure that the user trying export to excel is having enough permission on the list also.

Answer (score 2):

I tried and the below URL made dynamically can help you to get excel imported.

> https://test.sharepoint.com/_vti_bin/owssvr.dll?CS=65001&Using=_layouts/15/query.iqy&List={F3A732BB-355B-42BE-A7D0-08994B5CB0E9}&View={FAD0BA53-B5A5-4E52-8A76-5AED6C2615F8}&RootFolder=/Lists/List
>   A&CacheControl=1

But make sure to have SharePoint Compatible foundation installed. In case you have multiple versions of office installed on your system. 
Refer this for more details: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/emeaoffice/2013/04/29/you-get-an-error-message-when-you-open-an-office-file-from-sharepoint-on-a-computer-on-which-you-installed-more-than-one-version-of-office/

Answer (score 0):

When you export data from sharepoint lists, you download a ".IQY" file.
These IQY files are built with parameters like list GUID, view GUID etc...

Basically it's not SHAREPOINT exporting data... it is excel GETTING data from SharePoint when you open the IQY file.

A nice thing to see this being done is:
1 - Click in Export to Excel into your list
2 - Click in open in IQY file
3 - Click in properties (already in excel)
4 - Click into the "definitions" tab

There you will be able to check the parameters of your iqy file.

This could be useful to automate things... consider that you can use the "update data from source" in excel. Making a "dynamic spreadsheet" for your users.

I hope it helps!